# Mistakenly deleted a orchard defined view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, view, orchardcms

To make some changes, I created a VIEW through ORCHARD's Shape module but later on I deleted it...

Now when I am running my website, it is giving me the error "HTTP 404 - The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependency) .... "

How can we restore the view (if name of the view is unknown)  ?

Comment: Maybe posting the full error would help? Is there anything in the log files that might be relevant?

Comment: There is nothing relevant to this error...

Answer (score 0):

You must have done something else than just deleting the view. Also, did you try to restart the apppool?

Comment: Then you must have done something else than just delete the view. In any case, there is not nearly enough information in the question to be able to tell what's wrong.